# How can I reduce the gap between items of GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

Example Captcha:

[image: Example Captcha]

Here are the codes of Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).getBitmap());
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
     (int) (parent.getWidth() / DataUtils.num),//DataUtils.num=3
     (int) (parent.getHeight() / DataUtils.num)));
     return imageView;
}
```

And the XML of GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_paly"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_top"
    android:layout_above="@id/ll_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
></GridView>
```

Please, how do I reduce the gaps between CAPTCHA images so this looks more professional?

Comment: Be a little more specific. Whether you want to reduce space between rows?

Comment: Yes! This is what I want to express. Can you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: Pls add your list item xml

Comment: I don't create the list item xml. I use a ImageView to be my item.  I am new

Comment: Its not recommended this way. You should probably start using the holder method. I will post a gridview example in 10 mins

Comment: May I have you email address?

Answer (score 1):

Use android:stretchMode and   android:horizontalSpacing.
This will make a fix gap between view.You can set it to 0.

```
<GridView
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/gv_paly"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_top"
    android:layout_above="@id/ll_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</GridView>
```

[image]

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(list.get(position).getBitmap());
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
     (int) (parent.getWidth() / DataUtils.num),//DataUtils.num=3
     (int) (parent.getWidth() / DataUtils.num)));
     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you remove your old code?Can you provide a screenshot with show layout with display layout boundaries on?

Comment: Please set a color background on you item.

Comment: OK.I will provide the photo as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't know how to upload the photo.

Comment: I added a photo too.

Comment: Please add you xml of item. Why the second item is larger than others.

Comment: I don't create the list item xml. I use a ImageView to be my item.Please see the method ----getView() The large one is the blankItem.I am developing a puzzle game.

Comment: Just change getHeight() to getWidth().

Comment: I tried but failed. I will create the list item xml and try again.

Comment: No.You screenshot is right.They are getHeight()/3 as you write in getView().

Comment: What do you mean? Should I write getHeight()/3 rather than getWidth()?

Comment: I mean you got getHeight()/3 when you wrote (int) (parent.getHeight() / DataUtils.num).In you photo, the item is getHeight()/3,isn't it?

Comment: Yes，I changed  the photoes ,and succeed.  Why?

Comment: Because your image doesn't fill the cell.You can try to setScaleType to fitXY.

Comment: Oh,I get it. Thank you for your help!